# AWS S3 Sync command at ec2 instance startup

Tags: amazon-web-services, shell, amazon-ec2

I want to run below command at my EC2 startup. This is an ubuntu 18.04 box. I have tried crontab (@reboot), User data startup script as per article [User Data](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/execute-user-data-ec2/). I can see that command is being run in both cases (I create a output log file), but actually it does not complete sync. If I run manually this command in terminal this works perfectly fine.

```
aws s3 sync s3://mybucket s3://mybucket2
```

Yes I tried reboot and that aws link script as well. See below file structure and crontab expression. s3sync.log is empty one. Looks like cron run but it do not complete the command. or something else

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu        0 Jun 16 14:55 s3sync.log
-rwxrwxr-x 1 ubuntu ubuntu       58 Jun 16 14:44 s3sync.sh
```

@reboot sh /home/ubuntu/s3sync.sh > /home/ubuntu/s3sync.log

```
Content of s3sync.sh

aws s3 sync s3://mybucket s3://mybucket2
```

Comment: Does it give some error? Do you have some logs in cloudwatch etc?

Comment: I Updated my question there is no error

Answer (score 2):

Userdata will only ever execute the first time an instance boots.

You have 3 options:

- The `@reboot` cron option
- Create a [systemd service](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-automatically-execute-shell-script-at-startup-boot-on-systemd-linux) to execute the task upon reboot
- Wait for the instance state to become "running" and invoke an SSM command to trigger this, use [CloudWatch Events to detect](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/automating_with_cloudwatch_events.html) when EC2 instance state becomes running.

Comment: By default, user data scripts run only during the first boot cycle when an EC2 instance is launched, but you can change that behavior. See https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/execute-user-data-ec2/.

Comment: Yes that should be way, I have updated my question, But it is not syncing the files in s3